# drupal 8 commerce 2 - How to unpublish all published products and their products variations programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I need to unpublish all "active" (published status == TRUE) products and products variations  before every import of actual assortment on my site.
How to do it programmatically?
I see 2 ways to do this:

1. via a direct query to the database.
2. via entytyQuery methodes:
   2.1. create an array of ids of all products with the „status“ field == 1 (smth like that:  $products_ids = Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_product')->condition('status', 1)->execute();)
   2.2. iterate over the given array, changing all the „status“ fields to
   the value 0 and for each product getting its variations and assign
   them to the „status“ fields the value 0 (iterate over them in the
   subcycle).

thank you in advance for your help!

PS the quantity of products (with products variations) ~ 25 000 - 30 000 sku

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Add more information please.

Comment: Please edit your question with this information. The more information you provide in your question, the better people will be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. unpublish all products:

   $pids = \Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_product')->condition('status', 1)->execute();
   $products = Product::loadMultiple($pids);
   foreach ($products as $product) {
   $product->status = 0;
   $product->save();
   }
2. unpublish all product variations:

   $pvids = \Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_product_variation')->condition('status', 1)->execute();
   $product_variations = ProductVariation::loadMultiple($pvids);
   foreach ($product_variations as $product_var) {
   $product_var->status = 0;
   $product_var->save();
   }

Perhaps there is a more productive way to do this? I would be grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

the same solution, only through a direct query to the database:

```
 $query = \Drupal::database()->update('commerce_product_field_data');
  $query->fields([
    'status' => 0
  ]);
  $query->condition('status', 1);
  $query->execute();
```